# PHP oAuth removes the location from the received headers

Tags: php, oauth, linkedin-api

My use case:
Trying to issue a PUT request to move a post from a group's general discussions to job discussions.

To issue that request you need a [typical ugly piece of LinkedIn XML](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/has-anybody-posted-jobs-career-discussion-using-groups-api) along with the post id in the URL.

The problem is that the post id is only present as part of the received location header, which is obtained from the POST request(not at the response body).

Any solution except using packet sniffing?

[This OPEN bug from 2011](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59672&thanks=6), describes the same issue.

[LinkedIn forum question](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/php-sdk-sharing-groups-doesnt-return-location-header-nor-created-post-id)

Comment: Are you using a cURL connection and/or the oAuth PECL library?

Comment: Using PECL oAuth unfortunately.
It'll be nice to get an independent fetch function implementation that gets all of it's dependencies through parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using PECL oAuth library, try using the [OAuth::disableRedirects function](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/oauth.disableredirects.php).

Comment: No idea, from my end, Oleg, I fear.

Comment: That leaves me with... nothing :(

Comment: Any idea on how to implement oAuth authentication with PHP(PECL extension only has support of oAuth1 and oAuth 1a)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that LinkedIn only return 201 with a location header in case you can post to this group without the need of your post being moderated(usually that means that you are the owner of the group).

At any other case LinkedIn will return 202(accepted) without location headers(the majority of the cases).